# JQuery Vector Map stopped working after I installed SSL Certificate. Why?

Tags: jquery, ssl, jvectormap

Following is the code for Vector World Map in [index.html](https://analytics.ebenezer-isaac.com/):

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h4>World Traffic Frequency</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="Vector-map-js">
        <div id="vmap" class="vmap" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am using the following code in [analytics.js](https://analytics.ebenezer-isaac.com/js/analytics.js) to set the data:

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_en',
        backgroundColor: null,
        color: '#ffffff',
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        selectedColor: '#1de9b6',
        enableZoom: true,
        showTooltip: true,
        values: map_data,
        scaleColors: ['#1de9b6', '#03a9f5'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
    });
```

where

```
var map_data = {"us": "778","nl": "1","in": "230","ie": "1","ca": "60","gb": "39","de": "73",......};
```

and I am not using http to get the resources, so I cant locate where it is going wrong.

```
<script defer src="js/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
```

The map was working well, just before I installed the SSL certificate. Removing SSL makes the map work. There is no problem with displaying any other statistics on the page.

Comment: Does [this](https://blog.sucuri.net/2016/04/how-to-find-and-fix-mixed-content-warnings-https.html) help

Comment: @RobMoll Yes, thank you, it did the trick.